# Backbone localstorage

Tags: backbone.js

All, I am a noob in Backbone, The question I asked maybe is easy for you .
Recently I began to learn it from some basic tutorials, I found many demos mentions the `localstorage` which I can't understand .
Say we have some code like this.

```
window.EmployeeList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Employee,
        localStorage: new Store("employees")
    });
```

Can anyone help to tell me where is the data `employee` stored in ? What is the `localStorage`? thanks.

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localStorage is a small database built into the browser. Usually it is for small Data <5MB

You can think of it as a better form of a cookie. You can create stores like your "employees" store and save data to it like a normal database.

This should improve performance and capabilities of modern web applications. For example google mail uses this localstorage to keep a local copy of your inbox in case your client is offline (no network on mobile devices)

You can inspect the localstorage e.g. in google chrome by F12 -> Resources -> LocalStorage

Comment: Hi, pfried, does local storage exists in all main-stream browser like ie, firefox , safari? thanks, Anyway, Can I use it in pure javascript?

Comment: Hey, yes it is available in all modern browsers, see the Link from Pramod under you question, where you can find examples in vanilla JavaScript too